# Independence of Gaussian variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

I want to solve the following problem:

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two independent, Gaussian variables, with mean zero and common variance $\sigma^2$. Let $R^2 = X^2+ Y^2$ and $Z = \arctan (X/Y)$. I know that in this case $R^2$ has an exponential distribution and $Z$ has a uniform distribution. However, are $R$ and $Z$ independent from each other?

Comment: Yes: The distribution is radially symmetric, when plotted on the usual Cartesian plane.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks. But could u explain it in a easier way? I mean, can we solve the problem by using the definition of independence.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so.  A joint distribution of two i.i.d. random variables is not in general radially symmetric (not even when constrained to be zero mean and, say, unit variance).  The normal distribution is special in this regard and at least *some* of its specifics must be taken into account in the demonstration.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, let $X=R\cos\Theta$ and $Y = R\sin\Theta$ where $R \in [0,\infty)$ and $\Theta \in [0,2\pi)$. Then, for $r \in [0,\infty), \theta \in [0,2\pi)$,
\begin{align}
F_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta) & = P\{R \leq r, \Theta\leq \theta\}\\
&= P\{(X,Y) \in ~\text{sector of circle of radius $r$ and angle $\theta$}\}\\
&= \iint_{\text{sector}} \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy
\end{align}
Change to polar coordinates $(\rho,\psi)$ and evaluate the integral to get
\begin{align}F_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta) &= \int_0^r\int_0^\theta \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \,\rho\,\mathrm d\psi \,\mathrm d\rho
\\
&=\int_0^r \frac{\rho}{\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \,\mathrm d\rho\int_0^\theta \frac{1}{2\pi}\,\mathrm d\psi \\
&= \left[-\exp\left(-\frac{\rho^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\bigg|_0^r\right] \cdot \left[\frac{\psi}{2\pi}\bigg|_0^\theta\right]\\
&=\left[1 -\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\right]\frac{\theta}{2\pi} \tag{1}\\
&= F_R(r)\cdot F_\Theta(\theta)\end{align}
which shows that $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent random variables, and also that $R$ is a Rayleigh random variable while $\Theta$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$.

**Comment:** I wish to thank @Titus for pointing out the error in what I had written in the first version of this answer and also for insisting that his calculation of $F_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)$ was correct by gently asking where the error was in *his* calculation. Upon multiplying out the right hand side of $(1)$ and re-arranging terms, we *do* get his result
$$F_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta) = -\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) + \frac{\theta}{2\pi}.$$

Comment: I think you made a mistake when you evaluated the integral. Shouldn't you get: $F_{R,\Theta}(r, \theta) = -\dfrac{\theta}{2\pi}\exp\bigg(-\dfrac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg) + \dfrac{\theta}{2\pi}$?

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Titus You are absolutely correct and I have deleted my previous comment. Please see my revised answer.