# Independence of $x = z_1^2 + z_2^2$ and $y = z_2 / z_1$, with $z_1, z_2$ having a standart normal distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I'm trying to prove the independence of  $x = z_1^2 + z_2^2$ and $y = z_2 / z_1$, with $z_1, z_2$ having a standart normal distribution. Knowing that $z_1$ and $z_2$ are independent from each other.

I know   $x$ is like the $r^2$ of a polar coordinate. And $y$ is like $arctg(\alpha)$. But I still don't know how to use that to prove what I want.

Things I'm trying todo since I posted the question:

Trying to use Jacobian method to at least find $f_{X,Y}$, if I could then find $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$ I could prove the independence using the definition.

Things I've done since first posted:

I have found $f_{Z_1,Z_2} (z_1,z_2) = f_{Z_1}(z_1)*f_{Z_2}(z_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi}*e^{\frac{-(z_1^2 + z_2^2)}{2}}$

Some ideas:

I'm stuck trying to find the inverse of the transformation, but if there was a way to find it I'd be closer to know the distribution of $f_{X,Y}$

If I do something along $z_1 = r*cos(\theta), z_2 = r*sin(\theta)$, then I have $X = r^2, Y = tan(\theta)$,  maybe it's better to do two "easy" transformations than a hard one.

That transformation leads to

$z_2/z_1 = tan(\theta)$

$\sqrt{z_1^2 + z_2 ^ 2} = r$

Then going by the jacobian method, saying that g is the transformation. I have that

$f_{R,\theta}(r,\theta) = f_{z_1,z_2}(r*cos(\theta), r*sin(\theta))*J(g^-1(r,\theta)) = f_{z_1,z_2}(r*cos(\theta), r*sin(\theta))*r$

$ = \frac{r}{2\pi}*e^{-r^2/2}$

Then we have the other one,

$x = r^2$

$y = tan(\theta)$

Once again I go with the jacobian method,

$|J(t^{-1}(X,Y)| =   | \begin{bmatrix}
                           \frac{\partial \sqrt{x}}{\partial x} & 
                           \frac{\partial \sqrt{x}}{\partial y}  & \\
                           \frac{\partial \arctan(y)}{\partial x} & 
                           \frac{\partial arctan(y)}{\partial y}
                       \end{bmatrix} |
                 = | \begin{bmatrix}
                           \frac{1}{2*x^{2}} & 
                           0  & \\
                           0 & 
                           \frac{1}{1 + y^2}
                    \end{bmatrix}  | = \frac{1}{2\sqrt(x)*(1+y^{2})}$

$f_{r,\theta}(\sqrt(x),arctan(\theta)) = \frac{1}{2\pi}*e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$

$f_{x,y} = \frac{1}{2\pi}*\sqrt{x}*e^{-\frac{x}{2}}*\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}*(1+y^{2}) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{4\pi*(1+y^2)}$

This is close to the answer, because X has an exponential distribution, and Y another one. But there is a mistake somewhere, because the probability of Y being any number is $1/2$ instead of $1$

Comment: You could try to show $P(X \le x, Y\le y)=P(X \le x)P(Y \le y)$

Comment: But then I have to find the distribution of $X$, $Y$, and $X,Y$, and I don't know how to do that. But I suppose that if there isn't any other way I'm going to try to discover how to do that.

Comment: Isnt this the inverse of (or related to) the Box-Muller transform? Box-Muller generates two independent $N(0,1)$ from two independent $U(0,1)$.

Comment: "I have found $f_{X,Y} (x,y) = f_{X}(x)*f_y(y)$" Thus, exercise closed?

Comment: Sorry, wanted to say $f_{z_1}$ and so on ... already corrected that. Thanks for pointing that

Comment: See math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266214

Comment: The answer to [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2266214) shows that $\sqrt X$ and $Y$ are independent and so $X$ and $Y$ are also independent.  I vote to close this question

Comment: It shows that $\sqrt{x}$ and $arctg(y)$ are. I don't know if that implies that $X$ are $Y$ independent. But, if there is  a way that I don't know to affirm that, then yes, the problem is the same.

Comment: If you do not know why, if some random variables $U$ and $V$ re independent then $f(U)$ and $g(V)$ are independent, for every measurable functions $f$ and $g$, then this is the question you should be asking...