# A problem about uniform distribution and Rayleigh distribution

Tags: probability, density-function

How can I prove this staments?

> Let $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables with common distribution $N(0,1)$. Prove that  $R=\sqrt{X^{2}+Y^{2}}$ and $\Theta=\tan^{-1}(Y/X)$ also independent random variables, $\Theta \sim U(0,2\pi)$ and $R$ has Rayleigh's distribution, this's has density $$f_{R}(r)=re^{-r^{2}/2}, r>0$$

**My approach:** By hypothesis, we have that $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$$and since that $$f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp \left(-\frac{x^{2}}{2} \right)$$
and $$f_{Y}(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp \left(-\frac{y^{2}}{2} \right)$$
So, $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp \left(-\frac{x^{2}}{2} \right)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp \left(-\frac{y^{2}}{2} \right)$$
we need to find the PDF of $R=\sqrt{X^{2}+Y^{2}}$.

and we need to prove that  $$f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)=f_{r}(r)f_{\Theta}(\theta)$$ where $f$ is de PDF.

---

But, I don't know how can I write here $f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)$ and the marginal functions $f_{R}(r)$ and $f_{\Theta}(\theta)$. 
In the previuous problem I proved that $X^{2}+Y^{2}\sim \chi^{2}(2)$. I think that I can use that result, since that $R^{2}=\chi^{2}(2)$. But, I don't sure about my approach.

Comment: Please take some time to search the site.

Comment: I was looking for here in MathSE, but all the answers about this question they didn't carry out the demonstration itself, they only commented on the result.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2266214/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2959094/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1932170/321264

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left ( -\frac{1}{2} (x^2+y^2)\right )
$$
Note further that $X = R \sin \Theta, Y=R \cos \Theta$

Now, we can use the density transform formula to write
$$
f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta) = f_{X,Y}(r \sin \theta, r\cos\theta)|J|^{-1}
$$
where $|J|^{-1}$ is the inverse Jacobian of the transformation, you should be able to show $|J|^{-1} = r$. Putting this together we have

$$
f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} r e^{-r^2/2} \mathbb{1}\{r >0\} \mathbb{1}\{0\le\theta \le 2\pi\}
= \left ( \frac{1}{2 \pi} \mathbb{1}\{0\le\theta \le 2\pi\} \right ) \left (r e^{-r^2/2} \mathbb{1}\{r >0\} \right)
$$
and the result follows immediately (independence holds due to the fact that the density factorizes)

Comment: I have a question, the density transform formula is with $|J|^{-1}$ or $|J|$? In my textbook they say is $|J|$. Can you explain me that part?

Comment: Also, your explication is exactly that I was looking for here. Thank so much.

Comment: I calculated of Jacobian and I found that $$J(r,\theta)=\begin{vmatrix} \partial_{r}(x) & \partial_{\theta}(x)\\ \partial_{r}(y) & \partial_{\theta}(y) \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\cos(\theta) & -R\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & R\cos(\theta) \end{vmatrix}=R$$

Comment: Ok, I understand, You can use that $J(x,y)=J(y,x)^{-1}$. Thank you for you explication about my question.